# trisurf doesn't work in my MATLAB GUI code

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot

I am trying to write a code that plots a convex hull of some points that I generated with convhulln.  I have the triangle data (n by 3 matrix), and the Cartesian coordinates of the points (m by 3).  Normally, when I'm not dealing with the GUI, I can just do the following, and have no problems:

```
a=rand(20,3);
t=convhulln(a);
trisurf(t,a(:,1),a(:,2),a(:,3));
```

This works just fine. But when I try to do the same thing within the code of the GUI, it does not work. Here's what I have:

```
tt=convhulln(cluster);
trisurf(handles.trisurf_area,tt,cluster(:,1),cluster(:,2),cluster(:,3));
```

`trisurf_area` is the tag of the plot area.

I should also note that the following code works perfectly fine:

```
scatter3(handles.trisurf_area,cluster(:,1),cluster(:,2),cluster(:,3));
```

I use MATLAB 2012a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `trisurf(tt,a(:,1),a(:,2),a(:,3),'Parent',handles.trisurf_area)`.